# Maintain sessions in custom WebView Xamarin

Tags: session, xamarin, webview, custom-renderer

I am using custom renderer for WebView to send headers in request in my PCL project. I am sending session token and i dont need to type password and login name. Thing is when I start to navigate in webview it throws me to the login page and makes me login. When I login normaly it saves session.

My question is how can I save session when I accesse the page using session token?

Comment: The session is a cookie or what?

Comment: @Cheesebaron i am not sure, i guess so.

Comment: I am having the same problem. What I am able to see is that despite setting session values in my server code, no session cookie is present when I inspect the webview in the chrome dev tools. Cookies I create manually are. This is driving me nutz.